# Conditional PHP based on whether a file exists

Tags: php, file-handling

1.json and 2.json already created in DIR I want replace val1 with Value1 if file already exists if file not exists then create file place val1 =0

My code is below:

```
 $value1 = 1;
 $value2 = 5;
while($value1<$value2) {
    $data = array('Val1' => 0,'Val2' => 0, );
    $myFile = $value1.".json";
   
    if (is_file($myFile)) { 
        $filecon = file_get_contents($myFile);
        $strr = json_decode($filecon);
        $strr->Delux = $value1;
        $final1 = json_encode($strr);
         $path1 = fopen($myFile, "w");
        fwrite($path1, $final1);
        fclose($path1); 
              
    }else{
         $final = json_encode($data);
          $path = fopen($myFile, "w");
        fwrite($path, $final);
        fclose($path); 
       } 
    $value1++;
}
```

Expected output

```
   1.json = { "Val1" : "1","Val2" : "0" }
   2.json = { "Val1" : "2","Val2" : "0" }
   3.json = { "Val1" : "0","Val2" : "0" }
   4.json = { "Val1" : "0","Val2" : "0" }
```

but output is:

```
   1.json = { "Val1" : "1","Val2" : "0" }
   2.json = { "Val1" : "2","Val2" : "0" }
   3.json = { "Val1" : "3","Val2" : "0" }
   4.json = { "Val1" : "4","Val2" : "0" }
```

I tried with file_exists() but code is not passing to else statement. When I remove file handing code if-else statement is perfectly working.

Comment: Try file_exists($myFile).

Comment: Why would your code ever go to the `else` block if `1.json` already exists?

Comment: but it should go to else statement for 3.json and 4.json